# Refer to super in default values of constructor parameters when implementing an interface

Tags: interface, kotlin

Assume I have an interface that provides many immutable properties with default getters, as such

```
interface Repository {
    val name : String
    val pattern : String
        get() = "foo/bar/baz"
    var url : String
        get() = "http://mycompanyrepo.com/$name"

    fun add() {
        TODO("do something interesting here")
    } 
}
```

Now, there are several concrete implementations that just use most of the defaults. However, I also want to provide a `ConfigurableRepository` that allows for more flexibility in other projects that want to configure this at runtime, based on other user parameters.

**How can I create a primary constructor that has optional parameters?**

I was hoping something along the lines of:

```
class ConfigurableRepo(var name, var pattern, var url) {
   ...
}
```

**Edited for clarification**

The intent here is to use primary constructor behavior, where the named parameters are optional. More specifically, `name`, `pattern`, and `url` are all optional to anyone calling the constructor, and it will default to the interface's getters. But, I'm obviously trying to force the Kotlin `interface` to fit this model and it is probably a noob Kotlin user mistake, as I ultimately have no access to super here.

From the [class docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)

> In fact, for declaring properties and initializing them from the
>   primary constructor, Kotlin has a concise syntax:

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, var age: Int) {      
    // ...
}
```

I seem to be getting errors that this hides members of the supertype and requires the `override` modifier. If I try to override the supertype and then provide a default, it complains that supertypes aren't accessible in this context.

**Can this only be done in a secondary constructor with mutable
    values?**

I'm also open to suggestions/feedback on better ways to provide an interface that supports configuration over convention. The most important aspect being that the interface always provide defaults for a convention. Or, more simply put:

**Is there a better way?**

Comment: Is there a specific reason you declared `url` as `var`?

Comment: Just checked that in Kotlin 1.2.31 a `var` property must override both getter and setter or none of them. Otherwise it won't compile, because the compiler misses a backing field which an interface can't have.

Comment: I needed to add `set (u: String) {}` after `var url` in your `interface Repository` to get it compiling in Kotlin 1.2.31. And it think it makes sense that way, since interfaces never have fields, only abstract properties. (If you want fields, then an abstract class would be the way to go.)

Comment: I declared url as a var because the default depends on another member. I wasn't exactly sure if a val can use another val in it's default getter. Never investigated and seemed confusing to do so.

Comment: That is actually completely unrelated. Getters can do anything other methods can (including changing state be it for caching or other changes) and that's true for both `var` and `val`. For properties the main difference between `val` and `var` is that only the latter has a setter! So `val` should work in your case. (And it can be overridden as a `var` by adding a setter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html

Especially the 2nd paragraph around Classes and interfaces.

From these examples, a suggestion would be, if it's possible in your case, to use a base class instead of an interface. This would look something like this :

```
   open class DefaultRepo {
        protected open val name = "foo/bar/baz"
        protected open val pattern = "foo/bar/baz"
        protected open val url = "http://mycompanyrepo.com/$name"

        open fun add() {
            TODO("do something interesting here")
        }
    }

    class RenamedRepo(newName: String): DefaultRepo() {
        override val name = newName
    }

    class ConfigurableRepo(n: String, p: String, u: String): DefaultRepo() {
        override val name = n
        override val pattern = p
        override val url = u

        override fun add() {

        }
    }
```

Comment: I kind of knew this would be the first suggestion. It felt like I was "abusing" Kotlin language features to create more than an interface. Thank you for the suggestion. This is definitely the backup plan.

Comment: I understand that this is away from the original question. I just wonder if sometimes we're not trying to overthink the implementation. And from what you stated in the question, it's hard to figure out if this can fit your needs or not. But that definitely works, and allows your "default implementation" as well as customization of one of more fields as needed. Maybe someone with more knowledge than me will jump in and find a way to do the same with interfaces, eventually!

Comment: I always overthink it! And, I just asked the question here to hopefully learn some new tricks. I've already branched and started moving to a base class implementation. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since I now figured out how to do it with the `var`s, here an answer for the exact interface from your question.

```
class ConfigurableRepo(
        private var _name: String,
        private var _pattern: String,
        private var _url: String) : Repository 
{
    override val name get () = _name

    override val pattern get () = _pattern

    override var url
        get () = _url
        set (u: String) { _url = u }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, this is missing the toughest part of the question. Is there anyway to use super, or get the default if, for example, `pattern` isn't passed in? Assume there are 10 other properties, and I'm a lazy programmer who only wants to pass in 3 parameters. I'll edit my question to make this clearer.

Comment: In this case, a more Google-friendly way to title this question might be "Refer to super in default values of constructor parameters". Would you mind changing it to this?

Comment: Absolutely. That's a much better title. Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry, I was dug into the problem so deep, that I wasn't providing a clear description.

Answer (score 1):

Use an abstract class like this:

```
abstract class Repository {
    open val name = "default"
    open val pattern = "default"
    open val url = "default"
}

// example: only override name
class RepoWithDifferentName(
    override val name: String
): Repository() {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to have default values for the parameters of the default constructor like this (pseudocode, which does not compile):

```
class ConfigurableRepo(
    override var name, 
    override var pattern = super.pattern, 
    override var url = super.url
) {
    ...
}
```

Then the way to go would be the "null as default pattern" which one can always use when the desired default value can't be expressed in the method declaration. In your case, it could work out like this:

```
class ConfigurableRepo (
        override val name: String,
        _url: String? = null,
        _pattern: String? = null
): Repository {
    override val pattern = _pattern ?: super.pattern
    override var url = _url ?: super.url

    // ... more code ...
}
```

As you can see, the trick works with `val` as well as `var` properties and fields. Property `name` which does not have a default value in the interface is implemented with straight-forward field in this class.